# What is the orthogonal rank of Grötzsch graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How to represent [the Grötzsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph) as an orthogonal graph?

[image: Grötzsch graph[1]]

Comment: It would improve your Question to define the terms *orthogonal rank* and *orthogonal graph*.  I will add a picture from the Wikipedia article you cite, but definitions are the building blocks of mathematical arguments.